# Make Ruby interact with Node.js

Tags: ruby, node.js, pipe

I'm using Ruby EventMachine to build a realtime web application, so far everything works well, but I would like to add a feature which Node.js has a package for and Ruby does not ([node-canvas](https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas)).

I thought of replacing the entire app with Node.js, but I do prefer writing Ruby code over JavaScript. Furthermore, I'm totally new to Node.js, and although the web app code is not extremely complex, it will require time to rewrite it entirely from scratch with Node.

Is there an easy way that my Ruby code can interact with the Node.js module that I'll build specifically for this feature, maybe through piping or whatnot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up answering my own question, going to do it using Redis pub-sub capabilities.

Thanks!